# How to specify in CloudFormation the SourceArn for a InvokePermission?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, boto3

I have created an AWS Lambda function and I try to invoke it with [Python's boto3 library](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html).

Something like:

```
    client = boto3.client("lambda")
    response = client.invoke(
        FunctionName="MyLambdaFunction",
        InvocationType="RequestResponse",
        LogType="Tail",
        ClientContext="a string",
        Payload=b'{"param1": "ABC"}',
        Qualifier="string",
    )
```

When I run that code I get an `AccessDeniedException` error. So I'm adding an `InvokePermission` entry in my CloudFormation yaml file:

```
MyFunctionInvokePermission:
  Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
  Properties:
    FunctionName:
      Fn::GetAtt: [MyFunctionLambda, Arn]
    Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
    Principal: events.amazonaws.com
    SourceArn:
      Fn::GetAtt: [XYZ, Arn]  # <-- What to put here when invoking the lambda from boto3 library?
```

My question is, what to put in the `SourceArn` section given that I'm calling the Lambda function from the python code with `boto3` [client.invoke()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.invoke) function?

Comment: Access denied for what?

Comment: @Marcin access denied to invoke the lambda function I created

Comment: How did it go? The issue persists?

Answer (score 0):

If you get access denied for function invocation, it means that **your IAM user or role** that you use to run `client.invoke` does not have such permissions. So you have to add to the said user or role the following:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

You can change `*` for arn of your function.